# Send arabic characters by ajax - java

Tags: java, html, ajax, character-encoding

I am using java for my project.

I have a page include many textbox.

When the user type arabic string and push the save button the string be destroyed

For example:

- input: السلام
- after push button: %645D5$64%64f&%DF

I used this code for using UTF-8 on top of jsp page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

but it's not working.

And this is my ajax code:

```
var name = document.getElementById('LineTitle').value ;
var category = document.getElementById("LineCategory").value;
var lineDirection = document.getElementById("LineDir").value;
markerLayer.clearMarkers();
$.ajax({
    data: '{"feature": ' + str + ', "name": "' + name + '", "category": "' + category + '", "LineDirection": "' + lineDirection + '"}',
    type: "POST",
    url: "../SaveLine",


     beforeSend: function(x) {
                    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                        x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Is `%645D5$64%64f&%DF` what you actually get when sending السلام?

Comment: What does the string look like if you debug the javascript on the client side and what does it look like when you recieve it on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring MVC add this to your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If no, implement your own filter for character encoding and add it to your web.xml. Have a look at code of [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.java/?v=source).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue with some other data. I resolved by encasing the data I was sending from javascript with encodeURI().
You can use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() which ever works for you. 
Do tell if that works!

Comment: i used encodeURI and encodeURIComponent code but it is not working

Comment: if is use  encodeURI for data how can i decode the data?

Comment: For e.g.: You can do.
Name = encodeURI(name); or encodeURIComponent(name);
and then pass this modified Name in ajax!